# How to export Windows Address Book with Hebrew contact names

Tags: windows-xp, encoding, address-book

I have several contact names in my windows address book with hebrew characters in the names.  When I export the book to a csv, those names become ??????????.  How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure it's fixable, to be honest... I've had much trouble even with relatively basic stuff such as `ė` or `ū`, in the end I just copy-pasted everything to Outlook.

Comment: @grawity even when I copy and paste to Outlook I end up with ?????? in the names instead of the Hebrew characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really an answer within the scope of my original question, but I was able to do this using Windows 7.

1. I exported the contacts from XP's address book as a WAB file
2. Copied the WAB to a Windows 7 computer
3. Imported the wab file to Windows contacts on Windows 7
4. Used Windows 7 to export a csv

I know it's convoluted, but this seems to be a limitation of the XP Address Book export feature!